# Le « flexible seating » : le défi d'asseoir ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, traduction, anglais

À l'école, je me souviens de pupitres alignés en rangs d'oignons, disposés en cercle, en carré/rectangle, en îlots de 6, etc. Mais il n'a jamais été question « d'offrir dans une classe un environnement où les élèves pourront s'asseoir de différentes façons ou même se tenir debout » ([le Soleil](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-soleil/actualites/societe/201610/01/01-5026481-exit-les-pupitres-dans-la-classe-de-mme-marie-eve.php)) dans le sens du *[flexible](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/flexible/581136) [seating](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/seating/610134)* en anglais qu'un orthopédagogue a présenté sous le vocable de « classe multipositions ». Sur [Internet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flexible%20seating%2Cflexible%20*_NOUN%2Cflexible%20classroom%2C*ADJ%20seating%2C*_ADJ%20classroom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflexible%20seating%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cflexible%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bflexible%20tube_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20exchange_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20system_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20approach_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20response_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20cord_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20wire_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20material_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20manufacturing_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflexible%20shaft_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflexible%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2C%2A_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bregular_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bactual_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bown_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btraditional_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bordinary_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bopen_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Belementary_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsame_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bformal_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btypical_ADJ%20classroom%3B%2Cc0) (voir [généralement](http://www.edutopia.org/blog/flexible-seating-student-centered-classroom-kayla-delzer)) on trouve le *flexible classroom*, le *flexible seating*, et avec *layout*, *arrangements*, *environment* et l'idée du *student-centered* etc. L'idée du *flexible seating* implique peut-être une ellipse de *classroom* avec la « flexibilité » qualifiant le groupe *classroom seating*. Enfin il y a évidemment un lien entre les objets sur lesquels on s'assoit, le cas échéant, et la posture qu'on peut avoir.

---

- Est-on d'avis que la *classe multipositions* c'est naturel, clair et cohérent ; et surtout pourquoi ?
- A-t-on d'autres suggestions pour exprimer le *flexible seating*, en
  particulier dans une phrase où l'on débusque pour ainsi dire le *flexible seating* de quoi/en quoi/destiné à quoi etc., avec les nuances qui s'imposent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Est-on d'avis que la classe multipositions c'est naturel, clair et cohérent ;

et surtout pourquoi?**

Personnellement je crois qu’il y a mieux que *classe multipositions*.

La raison principale  pour cette ‘position’ (voire ‘opinion’ pour éviter mon faible jeu de mot) est, bien entendu,  «Off Topic» et sans importance ici car elle vient du fait qu’en anglais (ma langue natale), je ne crois pas que ce terme serait très naturel, clair ou cohérent dans ce contexte, mais peut-être au moins une des observations suivantes sera applicable en français.

En anglais, «a multi-position classroom [layout]» pourrait facilement être [mal] compris comme «a multi- [work]station layout,» où les élèves, divisés en plusieurs groupes, font rotation  d’un/e «[work]station» à un/e autre, d’une tâche  à une autre,  mais ça n’a rien à faire (automatiquement) avec «flexible seating» car les élèves risquent de trouver les pupitres et/ou tables classiques à chaque «station.»
Je ne sais pas comment on appelle, officiellement, cette ‘stratégie’  en français mais si le terme ressemble même un peu à  «classe/salle …  [à] multipostes, … [à] multistations, ou … à postes/stations multiples», ce n’est pas impossible qu’il y aurait d’ambigüité avec «multipositions» aussi en français.

Encore en anglais, quand j’entends   *multi[-]positon* tout seul dans le contexte de «seating», je pense d’abord aux chaises ‘Lazy-Boy’ qui permettent , bien-sur, les positions multiples pour s’asseoir, mais plutôt dans la même chaise (et pas forcement  «n’importe où/n’importe comment») et même s’il y a des *postions multiples*, elles sont déjà déterminées/fixées et donc pas si flexibles que ça en réalité.

Pour ma dernière observation contre l’usage de «multi-position» (encore en anglais et en demi-plaisantant, d’accord), quand j’entends *multi-position* en juxtaposition avec «classe», je risquerais à penser [louchement] que ça s’agit des études en Kama Sutra!

---

**A-t-on d'autres suggestions pour exprimer le flexible seating, en particulier dans une phrase où l'on débusque pour ainsi dire le flexible seating de quoi/en quoi/destiné à quoi etc., avec les nuances qui s'imposent?**

- Faut-il un adjectif et le cas échéant, lequel? Quelques possibilités et nuances:

Pour une alternative à «classe multipositions» en français, je crois qu’il vaut mieux avoir, comme en anglais, un substantif plus son adjectif, et  déjà pour l’adjectif, il me semble que  «flexible» (dans le sens «s’adapter/accommoder facilement aux circonstances»)  marcherait aussi bien en français qu’en anglais.

Si le sens «pliable/élastique» de «flexible» présente trop d’ambiguïté en français, peut-être  «alternatif» marcherait comme adjectif [alternatif], au moins jusque cette ‘stratégie’ devient de rigueur.

«Libre» ou même «ouvert» (les deux venant de «open [seating]» en anglais) pourraient peut-être marcher aussi comme adjectif mais attention car, au moins en anglais,  «open seating» est souvent flexible dans le sens de «n’importe **où**» mais pas toujours de «n’importe **comment**».

---

- Mais  avec quel substantif? Encore quelques possibilités et leurs
  nuances, avec une dans une phrase:

Trouver **le** substantif juste est plus difficile, car plusieurs candidats ‘logiques’ qui me viennent seraient ambigües en français, d’après moi (juste comme «multi-position» le serait en anglais).

Par exemple, en parlant de «le/la [?NOM?]  flexible des étudiant», il y a «[positionnement](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/positionnement/62846)» ou même «[placement](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/placement/61265)» qui auraient l’air de marcher d’après mon interprétation de *Larousse*, mais j'ai peur que «positionnement des étudiants» et «placement des étudiants» ont déjà la notion [trop] forte du positionnement/placement dans un boulot ou dans un niveau scolaire pour marcher sans ambiguïté ici.

Donc je crois qu’il faut trouver un substantif qui parle plutôt de l’ambiance/environnement en général   et surtout de l’agencement/aménagement/arrangement  des/dans les salles de classe/cours qui ont du «flexible/alternative [classroom] seating [arrangements]».
C'est-à-dire que je crois que ces derniers équivalents français des notions anglaises mentionnées dans la question (i.e., «[classroom] layout, arrangements, environment») marcheraient pas mal avec «flexible» pour capter «flexible seating», comme:

> «Le/un environnement flexible/alternatif/libre de/dans l’espace
> classe (de/dans la salle de classe/cours)» ...

... pour une notion plus générale qui peut (ou peut-être pas) inclure  l’arrangement et les sortes des chaises.
(voyez [ici, a *cursus.edu*](http://cursus.edu/article/25048/classe-inversee-episode-2-reorganisation-espace/) pour un exemple de «environnement flexible» et pour un usage de «positionnement» dans le titre qui peut-être contredit ce que j’ai dit sur ce mot au début de cette troisième section de cette  [trop] longue réponse.)

et

> «Le/un agencement/aménagement/arrangement flexible/alternatif/libre (des sièges/des
> places [assises]) de/dans l’espace classe (de/dans la salle de
> classe/cours)» ...

... pour la notion du vrai «physical layout» y compris l’arrangement/etc. des chaises (en admettant que sans l’addition de «des sièges» ou «des places [assises]», la notion générale  de «layout»  inclut plus que le «seating)», mais je trouve cette addition trop lourde est pas nécessaire).

---

- **Et, finalement**, pour «un agencement flexible» **dans une 'phrase'**

  (qui presente aussi «modulable» comme un autre candidat sérieux pour l'adjectif):

> « … un mobilier **modulable** : pour une facilité de transport et **un
> agencement flexible** [des sièges/des places {assises}] répondant aux différents besoins pédagogiques»

(voyez [*Espace et équipement*](http://ladecouverte.education/fr/espace-et-equipement/) de *ladecouverte.education* pour l’exemple cité de «agencement flexible» [avec les caractères gras et 'l'addition lourde' ajoutés] et aussi pour l’emploie de «aménagement» et «environnement» dans ce contexte)

(Bien sûr, anyone who cares to and/or has the time is more than welcome to correct as many of my mistakes as they can.)

Comment: Pavé César ! (Peut être essaye d'utiliser des titres pour séparer tes différentes parties?) Rien à redire sinon, je donne juste mon avis : j'aime bien l'utilisation d'*environnement*. En plus de ta proposition d'**environnement flexible**, j'ajouterais **environnement libre**.

Comment: @YohannV. Thanks for the good suggestions!